# Align with camera view

Tags: camera

[image]

Why does my object suddenly align with the camera when I clicked on *Align Active Camera to View*?

Comment: Have you accidentally hit Ctrl-0, which would turn the selected object **into** the active camera? (As opposed to Ctrl-Alt-0, which would align the active camera to the viewport view?)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.